# Why is the Merkle tree proof for m1 (H2, H34, H5555) and not (H1, H12, H1234)?

Tags: blockchain, merkle-tree

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9GU5.jpg)

article: "A Merkle tree [29], is a tree-like data storage structure used to efficiently verify the integrity of large data sets. In a binary Merkle tree, the most common type used in blockchain technology, leaf nodes represent individual pieces of data, such as transaction data in a block. Each leaf node’s value is the hash of the data it represents. The values of nonleaf nodes are obtained by hashing the values of their child nodes. The Merkle tree is constructed layer by layer from bottom to top until there is only one root node left, known as the Merkle root.The Merkle root value is a hash that represents all the data in the tree, and any change in the data will result in a different Merkle root. Merkle trees have numerous applications, such as verifying data integrity and comparing data sets. These applications rely on the collision resistance and one-way nature of the hash function used to construct the Merkle tree. Only when the data represented by all the leaf nodes is entirely identical can two identical Merkle trees be constructed, making them an effective way to verify data integrity. An example of a typical Merkle tree structure can be seen in Fig 1. The Merkle proof for m1 is (H2, H34, H5555). The use of Merkle trees in blockchain technology helps ensure the immutability and transparency of the ledger.
"

Is this a clerical error by the author? Why is the Merkle tree proof for m1 (H2, H34, H5555) and not (H1, H12, H1234)?